# Получить штрафы гибдд

Tags: json

Каким образом можно получить действующие штрафы ГИБДД по № машины или СТС автоматически? Или через какой сервис можно получить данные о штрафах.

Я знаю, что у них есть API (http://gibdd.ru/api/), но не совсем внятно расписан сам процесс.

В ручную можно проверить штраф тут - http://www.gibdd.ru/check/fines/, но нужно проверять машины автоматически.

**PS.** Так же интересует API по проверке наличия действующих пропусков на грузовой странспорт по Москве.

Answer (score 5):

Тут написано же красным

```
http://www.gibdd.ru/api/json/getDivisionsFull/
```

Добавляешь параметры и фильтруешь, но это только планируется и будет вот тут

```
http://www.gibdd.ru/api/json/
```

Comment: Если бы все было так просто, я бы давно уже сделал. 
Пожалуйста покажите тогда как получить штрафы по номеру машины?

Comment: А там по всей видимости и нет номеров автовладельцев есть только реквизиты http://prntscr.com/8v6jxq Если есть номер авто на котором есть штраф то можешь попробовать скопировать их форму на свой сайт, вдруг она не защищена.

Comment: Сайт у них на битриксе сделан так что всё в твоих руках, при желании можно и до базы добраться http://www.gibdd.ru/bitrix/admin/#authorize

Comment: мне нужен нормальный доступ, а не как вы предлагаете.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать https://developer.shtrafovnet.ru/documentation/reference/webmasters/overview

> ШтрафовНЕТ API служит для получения данных сервиса программным способом. Это автоматизирует создание систем проверки и оплаты штрафов ГиБДД, получение статистики и другие действия, доступные в веб-интерфейсе.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Хорошо. Учту замечания.

SMS/Email-уведомления, относятся только для конечного пользователя и не имеют никакого отношения к пользователям API (все уведомления происходят через postback'и) и полностью бесплатны.

Comment: Документация появилась. :) Спасибо, что обновляете ответ, хоть он и с минусами.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [API shtraf.biz для поиска и оплаты штрафов ГИБДД, Налогов и ИП ФССП](https://shtraf.biz/api.php)

Поиск в ГИС ГМП и ДИТ. Есть Партнерская программа с моментальными выплатами на WM, готовые шаблоны форм поиска/оплаты и шаблон сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос хоть и старый, но развернутого ответа так и нет. Постараюсь исправить этот недостаток.

На данный момент (ноябрь 2020) на сайте ГИБДД используется защита в виде Google reCAPTCHA. Дабы её обойти можно использовать сервис для обхода рекапчи (благо их великое множество).

Недостатка в таком подходе два (исходя из моего опыта):

1. сервисы для обхода рекапчи частенько дают плохой токен, поэтому придется самим городить повторы на загрузку (да, это не сложно, но денежка капает).
2. придётся самому набивать шишки при парсинге данных из ГИБДД (в основном разный формат дат, и даже через год может вылезти сюрприз).

Второй вариант. Существует несколько сервисов (парсеров), которые предназначены для получения данных с сайта ГИБДД. Все шишки они уже набили за вас. Вам осталось только послать запрос и получить ответ в json.

Третий вариант. Доступ к базе ГИБДД через СМЭВ. Но это долго и дорого. Подробнее [тут](https://hemulen-it.ru/2018/08/12/smev-price/).

В своей практике использую второй вариант из связки двух сервисов: [Твоя ГИБДД](https://ygibdd.ru/Parser/Gibdd) и [api-parser.ru](http://api-parser.ru).
Первый сервис дешевый, но иногда сбоит.
Второй - "надежно, квадратно, хорошо", но дорого.
Сначала стучим на первый сервис, если он не работает, то на второй.
По итогу получается дешево и надежно.

Небольшое предупреждение. На сайте ГИБДД не отображаются следующие штрафы: АМПП, МАДИ, Ространснадзор (МУГАДН), ФССП, парковки СПб. Для получения сведения обо всех этих штрафов есть специализированные сервисы, занимающиеся автоматизацией контроля штрафов ГИБДД. Кратко: вы добавляете в эти сервисы автомобили, а потом через их api получаете себе сведения о штрафах. Примеры сервисов: [Твоя ГИБДД Бизнес](https://ygibdd.ru/Business/Promo), [Штрафов нет](https://b2b.shtrafovnet.ru/), [Онлайн ГИБДД](https://onlinegibdd.ru/partneram/business/).