# Документация и доступ к API штрафов?

Tags: api, поиск-api

Как получить доступ к API штрафов без посредников, а напрямую к ГИБДД, ГИС ГМП и казначейству. Как в 2018 году осуществляется доступ к данным API и что для этого нужно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получить штрафы гибдд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461078/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%8b-%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b4)

Comment: Вот штрафы ГИБДД https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461078/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%8b-%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b4

Comment: Это не дубль, в той теме не решается данный вопрос. В АПИ Гибдд нет доступа к штрафам, а другой ответ - это посредник!

Comment: на странице проверки штрафов есть кнопка "Отправить сообщение в техподдержку", может стоит просто написать и спросить? а то останется только вариант  распознавать капчу и слать пост-запросы без всякого апи

Comment: Ваш вопрос, конечно, не буква в букву повторяет приведенный, но так же как и "дубль" получит либо такие же ответы, либо будет так само висеть без ответа. Там не решается вопрос - потому что галочку автор не поставил, и внятных завершённых ответов никто не написал. Возможно случится чудо и на ваш аналогичный вопрос ответы будут лучше.