# Бесплатный API штрафов гибдд

Tags: база-данных, поиск-api

Откуда берут информацию о штрафах всякие левые сервисы?

Откуда можно бесплатно и надёжно запрашивать информацию о штрафах?

Многие пишут про СМЭВ но я не понял как с ним работать...

Comment: Возьми аналогичные приложения и пусти трафик через прокси, будешь видеть с какими api они работают и сами запросы ;)

Comment: Обычно приложения запрашивают свой API. А это API уже в свою очередь запрашивают что то другое). - поможет ли в этом случаем прокси? - я не знаю...

В идеале нужен первоисточник данных) 

Спасибо за отклик!

Comment: [гибдд.рф/api](https://xn--90adear.xn--p1ai/api) - не оно? Или аналогичный вопрос:   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461078/11515

Comment: нее, там нету инфы о штрафах. Как я понял, там только инфа по адресам подразделений и т.д. Хотя, может я не правильно понял руководство? Везде предлагают платные сервисы(посредники), но они же где-то берут информацию.. Неужели парсят с сайта гибдд?)

Answer (score 3):

Большинство "левых сервисов" берут сведения из ГИС ГМП (можно получить доступ через различные платежные сервисы, главное оплачивать штрафы и, тем самым, окупать доступ), парсят ГИБДД и автокод (в основном, чтобы получить фотографии - в ГИС ГМП их нет).

Бесплатно получить штрафы не получится, к сожалению. По крайней мере на момент написания ответа (ноябрь 2020). Но можно получить штрафы ГИБДД малой кровью. В сети есть несколько парсеров, заточенных под сайт ГИБДД (не только штрафы, но и сведения по VIN-номеру и водительскому удостоверению). По моему опыту эти парсеры можно разделить на два вида: надежные и дешевые. В своей работе использую их сочетание:

1. Дешевый [Твоя ГИБДД](https://ygibdd.ru/Parser/Gibdd) - дёшево, но иногда сбоит
2. Дорогой http://api-parser.ru/, но надёжный.
   80% времени использую дешевый, а если сбоит, то дорогой.

Если интересует полная палитра штрафов (АМПП, МАДИ, ФССП, Ространснадзор/МУГАДН), а не только ГИБДД, но не хочется получать доступ к ГИС ГМП и парсить сайты, то и для этого уже существуют готовые решения. Например, [Твоя ГИБДД Бизнес](https://ygibdd.ru/Business/Promo), [Штрафов нет](https://b2b.shtrafovnet.ru/), [Онлайн ГИБДД](https://onlinegibdd.ru/partneram/business/). В любой их этих сервисов вы добавляете нужные автомобили, а через некоторое время через api получаете полный список штрафов. Плюсом можно проверять штрафы по ИНН организации или индивидуального предпринимателя.

По поводу СМЭВ. Сведения из неё действительно можно получать бесплатно. Но чтобы подключиться к ней нужно изрядно попотеть. Очень подробно описано в [этом блоге](https://hemulen-it.ru/2018/08/12/smev-price/). Кстати, в этом блоге есть много информации по СМЭВ.

Answer (score 1):

Бесплатно Вы можете получать штрафы в СМЭВ, но бесплатно к сожалению получить доступ к самому СМЭВ невозможно, такой доступ могут предоставить только платежный агрегаторы который дают доступ к оплате штрафов, но они берут за это комиссию, в основном это от 3% - 7% с платежа, у них есть фиксированная стоимость которую вы должны им предоставить в месяц, к слову она на сколько я помню начинается от 50к.

Можно парсить официальный сайт но там капча сложная, и в итоге выходит затратно. Используйте готовые решения. Пока лучше чем какие либо готовые API я еще не встречал.

Ранее работали с https://api-gibdd.ru, у них была скидка от объема (чем больше запросов) тем дешевле, сейчас не знаю как.
Сейчас вроде парсеров очень много, выбирайте то что быстрее работает, у них самое важное это скорость ответа, тестируйте и выбирайте.